# How to make WCF service available in a local network?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm new in WCF. I wrote a simple service:

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int Add(int a, int b);
    }
}

namespace WcfService1
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            return (a + b);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I let someone from my local network access this service?

Comment: Did you try anything to find information to that "problem"?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to host (I think that's what you actually mean by *publish* in that context) a wcf service:

1. Hosting in Internet Information Services (IIS)
2. Hosting in Windows Activation Services (WAS)
3. Hosting in a Console or Desktop application (Self hosting)
4. Hosting in a Windows Service

Where often option 1 and 4 are interesting if your service is more than a test project ;-)

Take a look at that tutorial for more information: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/550796/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-How-to-Host-a-WCF-Service

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You have to add an endpoint that has netTcpBinding. Also, you have to set the metadata behaviour for netTcp and set the address with net.tcp protocol as I posted in code below.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding>
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="Service.Service1">
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9009/service1"
              binding="netTcpBinding"
              contract="Service.IService1" />
    <endpoint address="mex" 
              binding="mexTcpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: @petros note that you can use other bindings as well. You don't *have to* use netTcp. You should update your answer respectively, Daniel. For a simple starting point I'd rather recommend a **basicHttpBinding**.

Comment: @khlr, petros asked that someone can access the service in local network. Using basicHttpBinding isn't always working properly with local area network.

Comment: Which problems did you experience? basicHttpBinding is perfectly fine for intranet scenarios, too.

Answer (score 0):

The person needs to add a service reference to your service provided

Here it is:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx

Comment: Your answer needs more explanation than just a link.

Answer (score 0):

you can host your service in your local IIS, just

1-add a web site in IIS and set content directory and port number

2-in content view, look for a file with .svc extension

3-browse your svc file (make sure your file is accessible for IIS_IUSRS group),
 this is your web service address.

4- others  in your network should, right click on their client  project and add a service reference.

5-they should paste your web service address, but instead of localhost in web service address, they should use your ip address.

Comment: I tried to host in IIS, but when I test connection i get error
"The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a built-in account to access the specified physical path. However, IIS Manager cannot verify whether the built-in account has access. Make sure that the application pool identity has Read access to the physical path. If this server is joined to a domain, and the application pool identity is NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify that <domain>\<computer_name>$ has Read access to the physical path. Then test these settings again."

Comment: @petros this is not error, it is a warning. in this step ignore this, try to add your web site and open your svc file and check if you have IIS error.